# How to prevent socket hangup in case of outbound requests that take long time in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I've a request that takes ~19 minutes to respond back (in browser). When I use Node's `http.request` for the same I'm getting the error `[Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET'` after about 2-3 mins. I tried setting `keepalive: true` and setting timeout to 20 minutes, but nothing worked. I even tried the `requests` npm module using it's `timeout` option, but that didn't work too. Is there a way I can get the response successfully?

Comment: Why is your response taking so long? These errors exist for a reason!

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: I'm on Linux. Server I'm calling is a Java service. I'm trying to write a client in Node.js.